# Application design forces structure of a query. Query returns duplicate results from Join. How to fix the result set with limited options?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to fix the result set returned by a specific query.  The query uses the following tables:

```
Inventory:
+--------------+---------------+
| Inventory_ID | Inventory_MFN |
+--------------+---------------+
|          302 |       0170315 |
+--------------+---------------+

InventoryItem:
+---------+-----------------+--------------+
| Item_ID | Item_Serial_Num | Inventory_ID |
+---------+-----------------+--------------+
|    1156 | 10095-001       |          302 |
|    1157 | 10095-002       |          302 |
|   25433 | 10095-003       |          302 |
|   30663 | 10095-004       |          302 |
+---------+-----------------+--------------+
```

It also uses a view that returns a result like this:

```
InventoryQuantity(view):
+--------------+-------------+-------------------+
| Inventory_ID | Location_ID | Location_Quantity |
+--------------+-------------+-------------------+
|          302 |           1 |                 2 |
|          302 |          31 |                 1 |
|          302 |          11 |                 1 |
+--------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT    i.Inventory_ID, ii.Item_Serial_Num
FROM      Inventory i
FULL JOIN InventoryItem ii ON i.Inventory_ID = ii.Inventory_ID
FULL JOIN InventoryQuantity iq ON i.Inventory_ID = iq.Inventory_ID
WHERE     i.Inventory_MFN = '0170315'
```

It returns a result set like this:

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| Inventory_ID | Item_Serial_Num |
+--------------+-----------------+
|          302 | 10095-001       |
|          302 | 10095-001       |
|          302 | 10095-001       |
|          302 | 10095-002       |
|          302 | 10095-002       |
|          302 | 10095-002       |
|          302 | 10095-003       |
|          302 | 10095-003       |
|          302 | 10095-003       |
|          302 | 10095-004       |
|          302 | 10095-004       |
|          302 | 10095-004       |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

But we actually want the result set to look like this:

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| Inventory_ID | Item_Serial_Num |
+--------------+-----------------+
|          302 | 10095-001       |
|          302 | 10095-002       |
|          302 | 10095-003       |
|          302 | 10095-004       |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

Due to the design of this particular application, the changes I can make to the structure of the query are very limited.  From what I can tell, these are my options:

- I can alter the tables and views referenced in the query.
- I can modify the view or create a new view.
- I can add some additional columns to the tables/view to join on.
- I can place a sub-query inside of one (or both) of the joins.

What do you guys think? Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that you really want is:

```
SELECT i.Inventory_ID, ii.Item_Serial_Num
FROM Inventory i INNER JOIN
     InventoryItem ii
     ON i.Inventory_ID = ii.Inventory_ID
WHERE i.Inventory_MFN = '0170315';
```

Or perhaps a `LEFT JOIN`.

If you have to following this structure, then I think this will do what you want:

```
SELECT i.Inventory_ID, ii.Item_Serial_Num
FROM Inventory i FULL JOIN
     InventoryItem ii
     ON i.Inventory_ID = ii.Inventory_ID FULL JOIN
     (SELECT TOP (0) iq.*
      FROM InventoryQuantity iq
     ) iq
     ON i.Inventory_ID = iq.Inventory_ID
WHERE i.Inventory_MFN = '0170315';
```

This basically negates the second `FULL JOIN`.